# How to Convert double to decimal (latitude / Longitude) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a piece of code:

```
Dim Latitude As Double = row("fltLatitude")
Dim Longitude As Double = row("fltLongitude")
```

Most of the lat/longs that are being fetched from the db using SP are retrieved in properly, except for a couple of records which do not include a period to indicate a lat/long value.
I have tried using these:

```
 Convert.ToDecimal(Latitude)
 CDec(Latitude)
 decimal.Parse(Latitude)
```

but none of them are working.
Can somebody help me out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do these values look like then? (Apart from that, your conversion happens too late; namely, after the assignment.)

Comment: What type is the object being returned by row when it doesn't work?  What does the debugger say the type of the object is?  What happens when it doesn't work?  Does it throw an exception?  If so, what's the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.
this issue occurred due to missing data in the database correcting which the issue got resolved!